# Are There Ancient Greek Words Descended From Sumerian?

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, cross-linguistic, greek, ancient

Does the lexicon of Ancient Greek contain words believed to be of Sumerian origin? If so, can some estimate of their number be provided?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Yes, a few: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Ancient_Greek_terms_derived_from_Sumerian

They were mostly borrowed via Akkadian, and into other major classical languages of the Eastern Mediterranean  beside Ancient Greek - Aramaic, Armenian, Persian, Hebrew...

English *cane* would seem to share such an etymology.

Another wave of ultimately Sumerian words came to Southeastern Europe later via Ottoman Turkish, eg *kireç*.  They are not found in literary Greek, but they are found in neighbouring South Slavic and Albanian, so surely they have been spoken in some Greek dialects.

Comment: This assumption regarding Akkadian, raises the question whether Greek borrowed directly from Akkadian/Sumerian or through an intermediate source e.g. an Anatolian language. For words like ἄγλῑς the loan might not have been direct and can have been borrowed into the substrate of Greek and from there to Greek. I find this paper below useful regarding this question.

https://www.academia.edu/2604857/An_Akkadian_loanword_in_Pre-Greek_on_the_etymology_of_Greek_%E1%BC%84%CE%B3%CE%BB%CE%B9%CF%82_and_%CE%B3%CE%AD%CE%BB%CE%B3%CE%B9%CF%82_garlic

Comment: Yes, that's a separate question.  If you look at the entries, most of them have a suggestion that it was not direct or that they were simply Wanderwörter.

Comment: κιρέτσι confirmed borrowed into Thracian and Constantinopolitan Greek: http://labweb5.duth.gr/erg_laog/arxeio/arxeio_thrakikou_laografikou_glossikou_thisavrou_t25.pdf, p. 133.

Answer (score -1):

When I remember right, the word βοῦς "cow" is traced back to Sumerian (it is believed to be a Sumerian loan into Proto-Indogermanic, the reconstructed form is *gʷṓws).

However, such beasts are rare and I doubt that there are many more of them, because Ancient Greek and Sumerian weren't in direct contact (temporarily and geographically).

EDIT: Here's another candidate: κύανος ‘dark blue glaze; enamel’, from Hittite *kuwannan-* ‘copper ore; azurite’ (ultimately from Sumerian *kù-an*).

Comment: 'Proto-Indogermanic'? I assume you mean Proto-Indo-European?

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut:  Indo-European or Indo-Germanic are synonyms to me, and I am not particularly consistent in using one or the other.

Comment: Etymonline suggests that the similarity with Sumerian may be because of the word's imitative origin, implying no actual loaning.  http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cow

Comment: My understanding is Indogermanic was used before it was realised that Celtic is part of the family and before Tocharian was known... it's a pretty unusual term these days, surely?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indogermanic%2Cindoeuropean&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cindogermanic%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BIndoGermanic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIndogermanic%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bindogermanic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cindoeuropean%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BIndoEuropean%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIndoeuropean%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It seems a bit unlikely that PIE would borrow Sumerian *gu* as *gʷṓws. Piotr Gąsiorowski has a neat [native IE etymology](http://www.academia.edu/1499772/The_Meaning_of_Life_PIE_gwih_u_) for the word.

Comment: In German you say "Indogermanisch"; in English you say "Indo-European". This is established and conventional nomenclature.

Comment: *gʷṓws is definetely IE. However, Whittaker is proposing that an amount of substrate words in Sumerian comes from an very early IE language he calls Euphratic. Among these words is also the Sumerian gud which would be an IE loan. Here is the paper if you are intrested: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=157C4AF50BD51F4EFBFEA2FF35BD8FF0?doi=10.1.1.516.4147&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: κύανος is obviously the origin of or at least related to English *cyan*, a shade of blue.